# Work with Fast Colored TextBox for Syntax Highlighting in WPF

Tags: syntax, highlighting

Is it possible to work with Fast Colored TextBox for Syntax Highlighting in WPF.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

I could not find an example that works with WPF c#.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you will have to use the WPF component called **WindowsFormsHost**.

In the code you create an instance of the `FastColoredTextBox` and add it to the windows forms host object like the example below:

```
FastColoredTextBox textBox = new FastColoredTextBox();
windowsFormsHost.Child = textBox;

textBox.TextChanged += Ts_TextChanged;
textBox.Text = "public class Hello {  }";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom `WindowsFormsHost` control and add your bindings as dependency properties to this custom control to pass it onto the `FastColoredTextBox`.
A more general example is explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d72458e-a332-450c-8a5f-972d9c5e20a5/how-to-bind-a-windows-control-in-wpf?forum=wpf).

But for this specific problem of binding the Text property:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using FastColoredTextBoxNS;

namespace ProjectMarkdown.CustomControls
{
    public class CodeTextboxHost : WindowsFormsHost
    {
        private readonly FastColoredTextBox _innerTextbox = new FastColoredTextBox();

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CodeTextboxHost), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(
            (d, e) =>
            {
                var textBoxHost = d as CodeTextboxHost;
                if (textBoxHost != null && textBoxHost._innerTextbox != null)
                {
                    textBoxHost._innerTextbox.Text = textBoxHost.GetValue(e.Property) as string;
                }
            }), null));

        public CodeTextboxHost()
        {
            Child = _innerTextbox;

            _innerTextbox.TextChanged += _innerTextbox_TextChanged;
        }

        private void _innerTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, _innerTextbox.Text);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<customControls:CodeTextboxHost Text="{Binding MyTextField, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not really answering your question but I found myself in the same situation asking that question and I solved it by using [AvalonEdit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AvalonEdit) instead. You can just WPF Bind to the Document Property and I even used it inside a Tooltip.

Here a minimal example...

WPF:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SnippetList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ToolTip>
                    <avalonEdit:TextEditor xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit" Name="FctbPreviewEditor" FontFamily="Consolas" SyntaxHighlighting="C#" FontSize="10pt" Document="{Binding Document}" />
                </Grid.ToolTip>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The class Bound to (ItemSource is SnippetList, that's a List of Snippet:

```
public class Snippet
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public TextDocument Document {
        get {
            return new TextDocument(){ Text = this.Data };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Child = _innerTextbox;

```
        _innerTextbox.TextChanged += _innerTextbox_TextChanged;
```

It works for me fine

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a complete example using a FastColoredTextBox in a WPF pop-up window.

I made a sample from what I found:

```
using FastColoredTextBoxNS;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;

// Create a Grid
Grid myGrid = new Grid
{
    Width = 400, Height = 400,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    ColumnDefinitions = { new ColumnDefinition() },
    RowDefinitions = { new RowDefinition() }
};

Window codeWindow = new Window
{
    Content = myGrid
};

//Create text box with syntax highlighting
FastColoredTextBox textBox = new FastColoredTextBox
{
    AutoIndent = true,
    Language = FastColoredTextBoxNS.Language.VB,
    Text = "if 1 <> 2 then\r\n'Some comment\r\n  Result = test\r\nend if"
}; 

WindowsFormsHost codeBlock = new WindowsFormsHost
{
    Child = textBox
};

Grid.SetRow(codeBlock, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(codeBlock, 0);
myGrid.Children.Add(codeBlock);

codeWindow.Show();
```